# How to get multiple windows in OpenTK

Tags: opentk

Is there a way to get multiple functioning windows in OpenTK?

When I do `window.Run()` it takes away control from me until it the window is closed.

I do not want to drop down to using GLFW for management because I want to continue using the OpenTK framework. In particular, the GL function bindings that it takes care of for me.